# Database Backup to Azure Blob

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

How can we take the backup and upload the database hosted in Azure through SQL (preferably, execute a procedure and get it done) to azure blob storage.

Comment: Read this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/export-a-data-tier-application?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Abhishek, i'm looking for a sql script that will take the backup and will export to the specified azure storage location automatically.Not a manual method.

Answer (score 1):

Below PowerShell script will export an Azure SQL Database as bacpac and will storage on Azure BLOB account.

```
$exportRequest = New-AzureRmSqlDatabaseExport -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName `
  -DatabaseName $DatabaseName -StorageKeytype $StorageKeytype -StorageKey $StorageKey -StorageUri $BacpacUri `
  -AdministratorLogin $creds.UserName -AdministratorLoginPassword $creds.Password
```

If you want to schedule execution of above export you can create a [RunBook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-first-runbook-textual) using Azure Automation.

Comment: Thanks for the update. i'm looking for pure sql script to do the same.